# Looping through a Global with a Matrix field

Tags: matrix

This might be a very simple question but I am pretty new to Craft with a EE background. Basically, I have a global containing contact details that use a matrix field, I’m literally just looking for the syntax to loop through the matrix blocks.

I have tried similar code to the successful matrix fields I have in other areas, but how do I reference the particular global? This is what I’ve attempted with no success:

```
{% for block in contactDetails %}
    {{ block.location }}
    {{ block.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

`contactDetails` being the name of the global. I’m sure this is very simple I just can’t figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{% for block in contactDetails.myMatrixField %}
     {{ block.location }}
     {{ block.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The handle for my global and my matrix field were stupidly the same. Thanks Jpea!